# Join 3 Tables with Sequelize

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to convert below raw query to ORM but couldn't achieve anything.

**raw query**

```
select * from "Invoices" I 
LEFT JOIN "Requests" R ON R."id" = I."requestId" 
LEFT JOIN "Supps" S ON S."requestId" = R."id" 
where S."confirm" = 'OK'
```

What I've tried:

```
  Requests.belongsTo(Invoices, { foreignKey: "id" });
  Supps.belongsTo(Requests, { foreignKey: "requestId" });
  Supps.hasMany(Requests, { foreignKey: "requestId" });
  Invoices.hasMany(Requests, { foreignKey: "requestId" });

  Invoices.findOne({
    include: [{ model: Requests, required: false }, { model: Supps, required: false }],
    where: { Sequelize.col("Supps.confirm"): { "OK" } }
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

But this generates a very very long query with multiple sub queries and wrong data

Comment: I request you to share the query generated by sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you will need to add also the `sourceKey` in th associations. ([doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#creating-associations-referencing-a-field-which-is-not-the-primary-key))

```
Supps.hasMany(Requests, { foreignKey: "requestId" ,sourceKey: '{ID}' });
Invoices.hasMany(Requests, { foreignKey: "requestId",sourceKey: '{ID}'  });
```

Also you can add `{raw:true}` to get a one level json response .

```
 Invoices.findOne({
    include: [{ model: Requests, required: false }, { model: Supps, required: false }],
    where: { Sequelize.col("Supps.confirm"): { "OK" } },
    raw:true
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```